# Tkinter.tclerror: no display name and no $display environment variable Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to run this code on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the Anaconda latest distribution of Python (3.8.3)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() # THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE ERROR

label = Label(root, text='Hello World!')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
 self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

However, when I run the same lines on the bash terminal on the python shell, everything works perfectly and the window opens with the label without any issues. I am using Visual Studio Code and the Anaconda distribution of python. I would really appreciate it if you could let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks so much, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[DISPLAY Environment Variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Graphical_desktop-related_variables)

> This variable is used to indicate to graphical applications
> where to display the actual graphical user interface,
> the value consists of 3 parts:
> A host-name followed by a colon (:),
> a display number followed by a dot (.)
> and a screen number.

@my machine, `echo $DISPLAY` => `:0` (have also used `:0.0`)

As per the Ubuntu wiki, environment vars can be set, e.g.:
`export DISPLAY=:0.0`
at the shell (before other commands),
or in configuration files (like  ~/.profile) (to persist).

My guess is that it's an IDE configuration issue.
First, try to set DISPLAY as described above,
in a shell; then run your IDE from that shell.
If that fixes it, add the export in ~/.profile,
for a permanent solution (will require log-out / log-in).

There may also be IDE-specific ways to config/set env-vars.
Can't test myself; you can search e.g.:
[is-there-any-way-to-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595446/is-there-any-way-to-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-code)
and VisualStudioCode's own site/docs:
[docs/python/environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Related: [what-is-the-display-environment-variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-the-display-environment-variable)
Other similar issues e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948685/tkinter-error-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0):

you can use it with python instead of shell

```py
import os

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')
```

**Note** based the display is **:0** to make sure on GUI run on GUI terminal `echo $DISPLAY`
Similar Questions 
[tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273204/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-python/75935058#75935058)
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38294/error-when-attempting-to-create-python-gui-using-tkinter-no-display-name-and-n